# Azure Runbook logs and streams not getting to Log Analytic

Tags: azure-automation, azure-log-analytics, azure-diagnostics, azure-runbook

So, I'm following this MS docs page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-manage-send-joblogs-log-analytics

I have diagnostic settings pushing JobLogs and JobStreams to Log Analytics
[image: Automation Diagnostic Settings]

I have a PowerShell automation runbook with the following lines:

```
write-output 'Fin'
Write-Error 'Test Error'
throw 'Test Exception'
```

I'm seeing the results of this code in the runbook Job status. But in the Log Analytics, 'AzureDiagnostics' queries return nothing. I've rebuilt the diagnostic settings. I suppose I could rebuild the Log Analytic (this is in test env.), but that seems extreme. What would prevent the log data from getting to the log analytic? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! So, I think rebuilding the diagnostic settings may have fixed it. I guess I just had to wait longer than I did. It took nearly an hour.

Thanks.